# how to cin from buffer x amount of times?

Tags: c++

I'm given a string of integers/floats and operands(/,*,-,+), each is separated by a space. example input would be "1 + 2 * 3 - 5.

I'm trying to use cin on the string so that it reads until the space and stores everything before the space into the appropriate variable. Here is my code and it works but it only works because I know how many operands and operators to give it, I need it to work for any amount of them.

If i only give it say "2 + 3" it still thinks it needs more input and I don't know how to fix this. I'm extremely sorry if this question is confusing, please ask any clarification questions and I'll answer asap.

```
int main()
{
    string input = "";
    float num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0;
    char operator1, operator2, operator3;

    cout << "enter string\n";
    cin >> input;

    num1 = atof(input.c_string());
    cin >> operator1;
    cin >> num2;
    cin >> operator2;
    cin >> num3;
    cin >> operator3;
    cin >> num4;
    cout << "num1 is " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "operator1 is " << operator1 << endl;
    cout << "num2 is " << num2 << endl;
    cout << "operator2 is " << operator2 << endl;
    cout << "num3 is " << num3 << endl;
    cout << "operator3 is " << operator3 << endl;
    cout << "num4 is " << num4 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you heard about loops? Try to use `while (condition) { statements; }`

Comment: @BhavinChirag well i was gonna do a for loop that went for i < input.length() but that doesn't work because i used cin and not getline for the string. what about while(cin >> input) { some code here?}

Comment: You can use `cin.eof()` to check for end of file (end of symbols in input)

Comment: so in my for loop i would have i < cin.eof() ?

Comment: no, you can use `while (!cin.eof()) { ... }`

Comment: @BhavinChirag oh that makes since, thank you, ill go try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop, read until fail. For example:

```
while(1) {
    int num1;
    char operand;
    cin >> num1;
    if (cin.fail()) { break; } // Exit the loop when failing
    cout << "Number: " << num1 << "\n";


    cin >> operand;
    if (cin.fail()) { break; }
    cout << "Operand: " << operand << "\n";
}
```

Comment: so your code is just set up for 1 operand and 1 operator correct? but i could utilize this way of thinking for more of each correct?

Comment: Not only one, this is an endless while loop, `while(1)` means `while(true)`, means **always enter the loop**, we only exit the loop when the reading fails

Comment: so i tried to implement your code but it always runs that first break statement right away.

Comment: Tried it on macOS, works. Tried it on rextester.com on VC++ and gcc and worked. Used the input like that `4 * 2 + 5 - 1`

Comment: @codyparker which platform do this code break on? and what is the input?

Comment: it enters the while loop, then it executes the first break statement. i input 1 + 2

Comment: I'm using mobaxterm and g++ compiler if that helps

Comment: is your while loop dependent on anything outside of it? besides the original string?

Comment: It doesn't even depend on the string. I think you read the string first, then use cin again to read. This means you read a string from cin, then read again. (It is obvious from your code). So, you could 1. Use `cin` directly without reading into string at all, 2. Use getline to read the string, then a std::stringstream to read from the string (not cin, cin reads from standard input)

Comment: This code just uses the standard input. It doesn't read any strings. This code is ALL the main function I used when trying.

Comment: ok i got it to work, but this just overwrites num1 and operand. how would i get it to store each number in its own variable like num2, num3....etc. and operand2, operand3....etc

Comment: Just push it back in a vector.     `vector<int> nums;`, `vector<char> operands;`     ...    `nums.push_back(num1);` , `operands.push_back(operand);`

Comment: @codyparker Vectors can be thought as variable length arrays.  You can even subscript it like an array  `vector<int> nums;` ... `int i = nums[3];`.  When you want to add something to it, use `push_back` (there are a lot of other methods). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @codyparker Try to read the "C++ tour" by the creator of C++ himself, https://isocpp.org/files/papers/4-Tour-Algo-draft.pdf